# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException computing the average

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm working on this book by Randall S. Fairman, 3D Astronomy with Java, having limited experience with Java myself. He uses this LineReader class instead of Scanner or anything to take user input. The exercise I'm stuck on asks you to use LineReader to get values for an array and find the average of the values in the array. This is what I came up with, doing my best, and it doesn't work. When I try to run it, it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Average.main(Average.java:10)
```

Code:

```
import ui.LineReader;

public class Average {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int average;
     int sum = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    int i = LineReader.queryInt("Give me a number: ");
    int [] M = new int [i];
    sum = sum + M[i];
}
    average = sum/5;
    System.out.println("The average of those numbers is " +average);

    }
}
```

Comment: LIneReader is a custom class, not part of the core Java API. So we won't know what that is doing under the covers.

Comment: You need to tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: When I try to run it, it says —  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Average.main(Average.java:10)

Comment: I updated with an answer. You don't need the M[] at all, just add the value of 'i' to the sum as you go.

Comment: So your question has nothing whatsoever to do with `LineReader`. The exception should have been posted in your question in the first place, and never in a comment, where they are illegible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `int[]M = new int[i];` line.

Just do `sum += i;`

Your updated code:

```
import ui.LineReader;

public class Average {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int average;
     int sum = 0;

     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        int i = LineReader.queryInt("Give me a number: ");
        sum += i;
     }

     average = sum/5;
     System.out.println("The average of those numbers is " +average);

   }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I'm not exactly sure how though, am I still accessing an array somehow?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. No, you are no longer using an array - it is unnecessary.